# Embedded audio clip not working

Tags: html, audio, embed

I've embedded an audio clip into a web page however when i run the page (on IE as is required for me), rather than giving me a audio control bar (pause/play/etc) it gives me a big white box (horizontal in the shape of the audio control bar) with up/down arrows on the side.

```
 <p style="text-align:center">

               <!--[if IE]><!-->

               <object data="overture.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" class id="02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
                codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="280" height="25">

                <!--<![endif]-->

                <!--[if !IE]><!-->

                <object data="overture.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" width="280" height="25">

                <!--<![endif]-->

                    <param name="src" value="overture.mp3" />           
                    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
                    <param name="autostart" value="true" />
                    <param name="controller" value="true" />
                    <param name="showcontrols" value="true" />

                    <embed src="overture.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" 
                    pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download"
                    width="280" height="25">

                    </embed>

               </object>
               </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking it out of a paragraph tag and putting it in a div first and also I believe your if statement for IE should be as follows

```
<!--[if IE]> -->
<!--[endif]-->
```

rather than

```
<!--[if IE]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
```

HTML5 also supports an audio tag, which is as follows:

```
<audio controls="controls">
 <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```